# How to deal with Savon Responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon, soap4r

I do not understand the people who prefer Savon to Soap4r.

How can I get the attributes of the returned object in a Savon response? With soap4r it's as clean as invoking a getter!

Apparently, in Savon I need to explicitly parse the response and walk the response_hash. This is way worse than the soap4r approach. Am I getting something wrong, or is Savon just a worse-quality soap4r?

edit: this question was due to savon not properly supporting multi_ref responses, as stated in an answer comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/raldred/savon/blob/master/lib/savon/response.rb

```
  # You can also let Savon translate the SOAP response body to a Hash.
  #
  #   response.to_hash
  #   => { :findUserByIdResponse => {
  #   =>   :id => "123",
  #   =>   :username => "eve"
  #   =>   :active => true
  #   => }
```

So you should be able to call hash[:object]  which would return attribute.

You dont need to walk the response object just call to_hash.

Comment: The problem is that when I tried to do this, I received an highly nested hash with very strange values looking like "#idN". Trying to do something as simple as response.companyId would be complicated enough not to understand where the value for this attribute existed in the hash. If i am not wrong the closest I came to this was something like response[:meta_refs][:companyId], what returned something like "#id3".

Comment: In Soap4r response.companyId simply works! Maybe I was giving the wrong parameters to savon, and it thus can't process the response in an appropriate way. as I didn't know what was the namespace supposed to be, I had simply done something like Client.new{ wsdl.document= "path to wsdl"}

Comment: Perhaps look over the documentation, your response object should be well represented with that hash if you are using the right parameters in the client.

Comment: seems your web service returns a multi_ref response? that's not directly supported by Savon (yet)